# Writing a function to update labels OnClick Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I'm creating a form that allows the user to select any number of Sigs so I can autopopulate a recordset with values.  I recreated an option group of check boxes because management/supervisors have said the default check boxes are too small.

[image: My Sig Form]I have this code, which works, but I want to know if there is a way I can create a more generic function that I can reuse on each OnClick event instead of pasting the same code with minor alterations 36 times.

```
Private Sub lblChkSig1_Click()
    mblnArray(0) = Not (mblnArray(0))
    If mblnArray(0) Then
        lblChkSig1.Caption = Chr(80)    'check mark
        lblChkSig1.BackColor = RGB(0, 128, 0)     'Dark Green
    Else
        lblChkSig1.Caption = ""
        lblChkSig1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)    'White
    End If
End Sub
```

The array `mblnArray` is just an array of 36 boolean values that I use to so I can iterate through them all quickly.  I have done this before, but only with as many as 4 values where redoing all the code wasn't an issue.  Now that I have a larger set of options, I decided I'd like to change it to make it reusable.

I came up with this function as a replacement, but I can't figure out how to dynamically change which label is updated.

```
Private Sub UpdateChecks(iPos As Integer)
    Dim ctlCurrentControl as Label
    Set cltCurrentControl = Me.ActiveControl

    mblnArray(iPos) = Not (mblnArray(iPos))
    If mblnArray(iPos) Then
        ctlCurrentControl.Caption = Chr(80)    'check mark
        ctlCurrentControl.BackColor = RGB(0, 128, 0)     'Green
    Else
        ctlCurrentControl.Caption = ""
        ctlCurrentControl.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)    'White
    End If

End Sub
```

I found out while looking for solutions that labels can't be the form's Active Control.  I also tried

```
Dim ctlCurrentControl as Label
Set ctlCurrentControl = "lblChkSig" & iPos
```

but that did not work either.  I don't know where to proceed from here.  I am not certain this can even be done, but it would be very helpful if there is a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use toggle buttons, they can even have an associated label that, when clicked, toggles the button. You could use a white X as the caption for all the toggle buttons, let the them appear with white forecolors (so you won't see the white X) and dark green color when pressed. Just play with the colors until they fit. This way, you won't need any code to toggle the color or caption.

As an example, I used

- Caption: X
- BackColor: #FFFFFF
- BorderStyle: Solid
- BorderWidth: Hairline
- BorderColor: #000000
- HoverColor: #008000
- PressedColor: #008000
- HoverForeColor: #008000
- PressedForeColor: #FFFFFF
- TextColor: #FFFFFF

Screenshot:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if there is a way I can create a more generic function
>   that I can reuse on each OnClick event instead of pasting the same
>   code with minor alterations 36 times.

That is exactly what **WithEvents** is for.

I had a form with 60 controls, and wrote an article on how to do this:

[Create Windows Phone Colour Palette and Selector using WithEvents](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29554/Create-Windows-Phone-Colour-Palette-and-Selector-using-WithEvents.html)

The core is this simple class:

```
Option Explicit

' Helper class for form Palette for event handling of textboxes.
' 2017-04-19. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
' Version 1.0.0
' License: MIT.

' *

Private Const EventProcedure    As String = "[Event Procedure]"

Private WithEvents ClassTextBox As Access.TextBox


Public Sub Initialize(ByRef TextBox As Access.TextBox)

    Set ClassTextBox = TextBox

    ClassTextBox.OnClick = EventProcedure

End Sub


Public Sub Terminate()

    Set ClassTextBox = Nothing

End Sub


Private Sub ClassTextBox_Click()

    ' Select full content.
    ClassTextBox.SelStart = 0
    ClassTextBox.SelLength = Len(ClassTextBox.Value)
    ' Display the clicked value.
    ClassTextBox.Parent!CopyClicked.Value = ClassTextBox.Value
    ' Copy the clicked value to the clipboard.
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy

End Sub
```

And the required code in the form is only:

```
Option Explicit

' Form to display the Windows Phone 7.5/8.0 colour theme.
' Also works as a basic example of implementing WithEvents for a form.
' 2017-04-19. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
' Version 1.0.0
' License: MIT.

' *

Private ControlCollection   As Collection


Private Sub Form_Load()

    ' Load events for all colour value textboxes.

    Dim EventProcedure  As ClassTextboxSelect
    Dim Control         As Access.Control

    Set ControlCollection = New Collection

    For Each Control In Me.Controls
        If Control.ControlType = acTextBox Then
            Set EventProcedure = New ClassTextboxSelect
            EventProcedure.Initialize Control
            ControlCollection.Add EventProcedure, Control.Name
        End If
    Next

    Set EventProcedure = Nothing
    Set Control = Nothing

End Sub


Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)

    ' Unload events for all colour value textboxes.

    Dim EventProcedure  As ClassTextboxSelect

    For Each EventProcedure In ControlCollection
        EventProcedure.Terminate
    Next

    Set EventProcedure = Nothing
    Set ControlCollection = Nothing

End Sub
```

Full code is also on **GitHub**: [VBA.ModernTheme](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ModernTheme)